# How do I calculate variations of a square matrix if the elements are binary?

Tags: matrices

I have a $3\times 3$ square matrix. I want to find out how many unique matrices I can create if each of the elements can be either $1$ or $0$.

How does the equation change if have $N\times N$ matrix?

Comment: Unique according to what measure? You mean uniqueness up to equivalence under similarity transformations $A=S^{-1}BS$?

Comment: Sorry I incorrectly labeled this question. Its actually an array, not a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $2$ choices for each of $9$ positions in the matrix, there are $2^9$ different possibilities.  And if there are $N^2$ positions,...

Is the matrix just an array of numbers, or is there more structure to the problem?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, 2^(N*N). It is just an array. Thanks!